TCA9548A I2C Python coding help
I am designing a board using 4 TCA9548As that each have 8 screw terminals so that I can connect to 32 addressable devices. I am trying to create the python code to be able to write to each of these devices. After doing some research, I have begun to use the TCA9548A library, but there isn't much online (very little in the Adafruit guide) to go off of. I am using their scan function to first detect which devices are connected and what their addresses are. Next, I want to be able to send write commands to a device I select from 1 of the 4 MUXs, does anyone have any advice? I just started learning python for this project, so I am very new to it and my coding knowledge is all from school projects I have learned in college during my 3 years of studying EE. Here is what I have so far:
import adafruit_tca9548a
import time
import board
from smbus2 import SMBus as smb

# Create the I2C Bus
i2c = board.I2C() # uses board.SCL and board.SDA

# Create the 4 MUXs and give them to the I2C bus
TCA1 = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c, 0x70)
TCA2 = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c, 0x71)
TCA3 = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c, 0x72)
TCA4 = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c, 0x73)

# Set the channel bytes for MUX 1
Ch0_M1 = 0b00000001
Ch1_M1 = 0b00000010
Ch2_M1 = 0b00000100
Ch3_M1 = 0b00001000
Ch4_M1 = 0b00010000
Ch5_M1 = 0b00100000
Ch6_M1 = 0b01000000
Ch7_M1 = 0b10000000

# Set the channel bytes for MUX 2
Ch0_M2 = 0b00000001
Ch1_M2 = 0b00000010
Ch2_M2 = 0b00000100
Ch3_M2 = 0b00001000
Ch4_M2 = 0b00010000
Ch5_M2 = 0b00100000
Ch6_M2 = 0b01000000
Ch7_M2 = 0b10000000

# Set the channel bytes for MUX 3
Ch0_M3 = 0b00000001
Ch1_M3 = 0b00000010
Ch2_M3 = 0b00000100
Ch3_M3 = 0b00001000
Ch4_M3 = 0b00010000
Ch5_M3 = 0b00100000
Ch6_M3 = 0b01000000
Ch7_M3 = 0b10000000

# Set the channel bytes for MUX 4
Ch0_M4 = 0b00000001
Ch1_M4 = 0b00000010
Ch2_M4 = 0b00000100
Ch3_M4 = 0b00001000
Ch4_M4 = 0b00010000
Ch5_M4 = 0b00100000
Ch6_M4 = 0b01000000
Ch7_M4 = 0b10000000

# Scan MUX 1 for addresses of connected devices

for channel in range (8):
    if TCA1[channel].try_lock():                                                                  # If channel is detected to be in use, lock onto that channel
        print("TCA 1 Channel {}:".format(channel), end="")                        
        addresses = TCA1[channel].scan()                                                          # Scan for the addresses of devices connected to a channel
        print([hex(address) for address in addresses if address != [0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73]])     # Give the hex address of the devices connected to the channels, address can't be same as the MUXs
        TCA1[channel].unlock()                                                                    # Unlock the channels
        time.sleep(0.1)
        break
    else:                                                                                        # If no devices are detected after the scan, break the loop and give no device found message
        print("No devices found on MUX 1")
        break

time.sleep(0.1)

# Scan MUX 2 for addresses of connected devices

for channel in range (8):
    if TCA2[channel].try_lock():                                                                  # If channel is detected to be in use, lock onto that channel
        print("TCA 2 Channel {}:".format(channel), end="")                        
        addresses = TCA2[channel].scan()                                                          # Scan for the addresses of devices connected to a channel
        print([hex(address) for address in addresses if address != [0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73]])     # Give the hex address of the devices connected to the channels, address can't be same as the MUXs
        TCA2[channel].unlock()                                                                    # Unlock the channels
        time.sleep(0.1)
        break
    else:                                                                                        # If no devices are detected after the scan, break the loop and give no device found message
        print("No devices found on MUX 2")
        break

time.sleep(0.1)

# Scan MUX 3 for addresses of connected devices

for channel in range (8):
    if TCA3[channel].try_lock():                                                                  # If channel is detected to be in use, lock onto that channel
        print(" TCA 3 Channel {}:".format(channel), end="")                        
        addresses = TCA3[channel].scan()                                                          # Scan for the addresses of devices connected to a channel
        print([hex(address) for address in addresses if address != [0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73]])     # Give the hex address of the devices connected to the channels, address can't be same as the MUXs
        TCA3[channel].unlock()                                                                    # Unlock the channels
        time.sleep(0.1)
        break
    else:                                                                                        # If no devices are detected after the scan, break the loop and give no device found message
        print("No devices found on MUX 3")
        break

time.sleep(0.1)

# Scan MUX 4 for addresses of connected devices

for channel in range (8):
    if TCA4[channel].try_lock():                                                                  # If channel is detected to be in use, lock onto that channel
        print("TCA 4 Channel {}:".format(channel), end="")                        
        addresses = TCA4[channel].scan()                                                          # Scan for the addresses of devices connected to a channel
        print([hex(address) for address in addresses if address != [0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73]])     # Give the hex address of the devices connected to the channels, address can't be same as the MUXs
        TCA4[channel].unlock()                                                                    # Unlock the channels
        time.sleep(0.1)
        break
    else:                                                                                         # If no devices are detected after the scan, break the loop and give no device found message
        print("No devices found on MUX 4")
        break

time.sleep(0.1)

# Print the MUX addresses for the user to see so they know which MUX adddress to use when they are writing to or reading from a slave device connected to one of those MUXs
print("The MUX addresses are given below:")
print("Mux 1 = 0x70")
print("Mux 2 = 0x71")
print("Mux 3 = 0x72")
print("Mux 4 = 0x73")                    

# Function to write to a slave device
def i2c_write(tca_address, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value):                                               # Address for the MUX you want to talk to, the desired channel, the slave's address, and what you want to send the slave device
    return i2c.write(tca_address, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value)

# Function to read from a slave device
def i2c_read(tca_address, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value):
    return i2c.read(tca_address, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value)

Muxchannel = input("Enter the MUX channel:")                                                                # Input the deisred channel of MUX 1
SlavAddr = input ("Enter the Slave Address:")                                                               # Input the slave address on the channel previously chosen
value = input("Enter the bytes to write:")                                                                  # Enter the value you wish to write to the slave device
length = input("Enter the length of the write function")

# Go through MUX 1
# Decide wether user wants to write to or read from a device connected to the MUX, if neither, pass on to next MUX or complete all transactions then pass on to MUX 2
while True:
    if TCA1[channel].try_lock():
        action = input("Do you want to write to or read from the slave device? (write/read): "). lower()
        if action == 'write':
            if i2c_write(0x70, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value):
        
                break
        elif action == 'read':                                             
            result = i2c_read(0x70, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, length)
            print("Read Result: {result}")
            print("")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input, enter either 'write' or 'read'.")
        exit_option = input ("Press c to continue to the next MUX or press anything else to continue:")
        if exit_option == 'c':
            print("Mux 2")
            break
        else:
            print("Select another channel")
    else:
        TCA1[channel].unlock()
        break
time.sleep(0.25)

# Go through MUX 2
# Decide wether user wants to write to or read from a device connected to the MUX, if neither, pass on to next MUX or complete all transactions then pass on to MUX 3
while True:
    if TCA2[channel].try_lock():
        action = input("Do you want to write to or read from the slave device? (write/read): "). lower()
        if action == 'write':
            if i2c_write(0x71, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value):
        
                break
        elif action == 'read':                                             
            result = i2c_read(0x71, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, length)
            print("Read Result: {result}")
            print("")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input, enter either 'write' or 'read'.")
        exit_option = input ("Press c to continue to the next MUX or press anything else to continue:")
        if exit_option == 'c':
            print("Mux 3")
            break
        else:
            print("Select another channel")
    else:
        TCA2[channel].unlock()
        break
time.sleep(0.25)

# Go through MUX 3
# Decide wether user wants to write to or read from a device connected to the MUX, if neither, pass on to next MUX or complete all transactions then pass on to MUX 4
while True:
    if TCA3[channel].try_lock():
        action = input("Do you want to write to or read from the slave device? (write/read): "). lower()
        if action == 'write':
            if i2c_write(0x72, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value):
        
                break
        elif action == 'read':                                             
            result = i2c_read(0x72, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, length)
            print("Read Result: {result}")
            print("")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input, enter either 'write' or 'read'.")
        exit_option = input ("Press c to continue to the next MUX or press anything else to continue:")
        if exit_option == 'c':
            print("Mux 4")
            break
        else:
            print("Select another channel")
    else:
        TCA3[channel].unlock()
        break
time.sleep(0.25)
# Go through MUX 4
# Decide wether user wants to write to or read from a device connected to the MUX, if neither, end program
while True:
    if TCA4[channel].try_lock():
        action = input("Do you want to write to or read from the slave device? (write/read): "). lower()
        if action == 'write':
            if i2c_write(0x73, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, value):
        
                break
        elif action == 'read':                                             
            result = i2c_read(0x73, Muxchannel, SlavAddr, length)
            print("Read Result: {result}")
            print("")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input, enter either 'write' or 'read'.")
        exit_option = input ("Press c to end the program or press anything else to continue:")
        if exit_option == 'c':
            print("End of program, goodbye")
            break
        else:
            print("Select another channel")
    else:
        TCA4[channel].unlock()
        break
time.sleep(0.25)

I'll take any tips, help, resources, or advice that I can get.
Do I need to create 4 different for-loops, each with a range of 8? Do I need to assign an object to all 32 channels and then the user selects the MUX, channel, and gives the slave devices' address? Do I need a for-loop with an if-statement for each channel that keeps running until the user has sent data to all the devices it wants to send data to?

To be honest, this question is not about how to use the mux, but how to use some random library on some random platorm that someone else made to wrap simple one byte I2C writes to the mux into a library that apparently has no manuals or examples or source code to read how it works. Sounds just like what Arduino people do. Would it made more sense to just send those 1 byte commands that select the channels yourself? Is the library the problem or the Python language? Would it make sense to use some other language than Python?

I think you're on to something. It's a library found from the official guide from Adafruit website for the MUX, but there's a lack of usage for it for my purposes (specifically writing to slave devices) so I'll start looking for other widely used libraries and/or learn to use and experiment with sending 1 byte commands.

But writing to the slave is what you need to do anyway, regardless of if you have a mux or not. And the mux library seems to show one mux as 8 I2C buses. And it looks like the Multi Sensor Example Code is exactly what you are looking for. Or maybe writing a for loop in Python.

I'll look more into that example; part of my requirement is scanning for the address of the slave devices then using that address to write to the slave device. It seemed like their sensor examples didn't show what write to functions would look like not using another library also that comes with one of those sensors. I may have missed something analyzing it though

Of course they don't have any write functions, because they use a library for the sensor. The point is to give the sensor library an I2C bus where to write, but you don't give it your main I2C bus instance where your muxes are, but ask the mux library to return an I2C bus instance that is behind the mux. So when you communicate with any sensor, it already sends that traffic through the instance the mux gave you, so the mux instance knows to switch that port on-line and then communicate with it so the sensor library does not even know it's behind a mux. The sensor address is assumed default.

I will try that, thank you. I went back and revised the code over the weekend. The changes are shown in the code on my original post.
